# Changing background color bugs the program? (ncurses)

Tags: c, colors, background, ncurses

So I have a rudimentary "snake" game made with ncurses.

When adding

```
start_color();
    init_color(COLOR_BLUE, 0, 0, 0);
    init_pair(1, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLUE);
    bkgd(COLOR_PAIR(1));
```

to change the background color, the program goes into a infinite loop. Debugging told me that the program stops when generating food. This is the code:

```
void generate_food(food *food, int nrows, int ncols, snake *snake) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int validLocation = 0;      

    do {
        food->x = rand() % nrows;
        food->y = rand() % ncols;
        if ( mvinch(food->x, food->y) == ' ' )
            validLocation = 1;
    }
    while (!validLocation);
    move(food->x, food->y);
    addch('*');
}
```

It checks if the random place is empty ( == ' ' ) and puts a '*' in it if so.

Works perfectly until I change the bkgd. It stops at the do-while, as if there is no empty space in the window. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `ncurses`, `mvinch` does not just return the character, it returns a `chtype`, which contains the character information, but also atttributes and color information. That means that in order to compare it to a character, you have to extract the character information from the `chtype`.

For this, ncurses provides a couple of bitmasks. From the manpage:

```
   Attributes
       The following bit-masks may be AND-ed with characters returned by winch.

       A_CHARTEXT     Bit-mask to extract character
       A_ATTRIBUTES   Bit-mask to extract attributes
       A_COLOR        Bit-mask to extract color-pair field information
```

In short, if you set a background color to your window, `mvinch` will never return `' '`. Instead, you could use:

```
if (mvinch(food->x, food->y) & A_CHARTEXT == ' ')
```

see also `man mvinch`